Dialogflow Messenger Fulfillment (Custom Payload) - Dialogflow CX
I am new to Dialogflow and have been having this concern for quite sometime. I need to ask the experts here. I wanted to use Custom Payload for my chatbot, to present a list of menu using either list, button or chips. However as per current logic, once user clicked it will direct user outside of the chabot to the specific url.
My question is how do i keep the conversation within the bot and just present user with the information required or another list of menu to choose from ?
As for example below code for button from this documentation : https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/integration/dialogflow-messenger/fulfillment
`{
  "richContent": [
    [
      {
        "type": "button",
        "icon": {
          "type": "chevron_right",
          "color": "#FF9800"
        },
        "mode": "blocking",
        "text": "Button text",
        "anchor": {
          "href": "https://example.com" // I dont want user to go here (out from chatbot)
        },
        "event": {
          "event": ""
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}`

How do i modify this to make the user stay within the chat and present the user with the information required / another menu. I am not very familiar with event, etc. Appreciate if you could provide an example for me, one example is enough for me to replicate for other use case.
Thank you
I wanted the list of menu/option presented, once user clicked it will remain in the chatbot window and be presented with that specific info/intent/list of another menu to be choose from.
